# python get difference from arrays

Tags: python

I have the following two arrays , i am trying to see whether if the elements in invalid_id_arr exists in valid_id_arr if it doesn't exist then i would form the diff array.But from the below code i see the following in diff array `['id123', 'id124', 'id125', 'id126', 'id789', 'id666']`, i expect the output to be `["id789","id666"]` what am i doing wrong here

```
tag_file= {}
tag_file['invalid_id_arr']=["id123-3431","id124-4341","id125-4341","id126-1w","id789-123","id666"] 
tag_file['valid_id_arr']=["id123-12345","id124-1122","id125-13232","id126-12332","id1new","idagain"] 
diff = [ele.split('-')[0] for ele in tag_file['invalid_id_arr'] if str(ele.split('-')[0]) not in tag_file['valid_id_arr']]
```

Current Output:

```
 ['id123', 'id124', 'id125', 'id126', 'id789', 'id666']
```

Expected ouptut:

```
 ["id789","id666"]
```

Comment: you only want to check the value just after `'id'`?

Comment: check out sets, if you clean your data you can do set(a).difference(set(b)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a set is more efficient, but your main problem is that you weren't removing the second half of the elements in valid_id_arr.

```
invalid_id_arr=["id123-3431","id124-4341","id125-4341","id126-1w","id789-123","id666"] 
valid_id_arr=["id123-12345","id124-1122","id125-13232","id126-12332","id1new","idagain"]
valid_id_set = set(ele.split('-')[0] for ele in valid_id_arr)
diff = [ele for ele in invalid_id_arr if ele.split('-')[0] not in valid_id_set]
print diff
```

output:

```
['id789-123', 'id666']
```

http://ideone.com/Q9JBw

Comment: I taught python interpreter will handle it.. id1  in valid_arr >>True

Comment: No, (x in arr) is True if and only if x == arr[i] for any i. See the first line of the table in this section: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange

Comment: Yes - you could replace set(...) with list(...) in my code, but it will be slower if the lists are large. x in list(...) is O(n) but x in set(...) is O(log n), which is faster.

However, your example was doing "id1" in ["id1-1", "id1-2"] = False, because the stuff after the hyphen hadn't been removed.

Answer (score 3):

Try `sets`:

```
invalid_id_arr = ["id123-3431","id124-4341","id125-4341","id126-1w","id789-123","id666"] 
valid_id_arr = ["id123-12345","id124-1122","id125-13232","id126-12332","id1new","idagain"] 

set_invalid = set(x.split('-')[0] for x in invalid_id_arr)
print set_invalid.difference(x.split('-')[0] for x in valid_id_arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    >>> a = ["id123-3431","id124-4341","id125-4341","id126-1w","id789-123","id666"]
    >>> b = ["id123-12345","id124-1122","id125-13232","id126-12332","id1new","idagain"]
    >>> c = (s.split('-')[0] for s in b)
    >>> [ele.split('-')[0] for ele in a if str(ele.split('-')[0]) not in c]

        ['id789', 'id666']
    >>>
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid two for loops

Comment: O(n * log(N)) using set, O(n * n) using your method, but you solution  can work very well!